# How to handle HTTP 204 "no content" in Restangular POST?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

I have a REST service to record user interface logs. The JavaScript is :

```
Restangular.all("log_tutor").post(information);
```

It works and I obtain an HTTP response "204 No content", which is expected for this service. 
But it writes in FireFox console "No element found".

How could it be possible to tell Restangular not to expect data from this call ? or to handle HTTP 204 code for this call only ?

The JAVA service is  :

```
         @Provider
        @Path("log_tutor")
        public class TutorTraceRESTFacade {

        . . .

            @POST
            @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
            @Transactional
            @RolesAllowed("TUTOR")  
            public Response create(TutorTraceDetail _trace, @Context HttpServletRequest req) {
                _trace.setMessageReceivedTimestamp(new Date());
                HttpSession session = req.getSession();
                String sessionId = session.getId();
                LoginUser user = FormIDApplication.getInstance().getConnectedUser(sessionId);
                Long c = tutorTraceFacade.create(user.getLogin(), _trace);
                return Response.created(URI.create(c.toString())).build();
            }   
    . . .
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a Javascript object `logEntry` which includes the data you want to save I would try:

```
Restangular.one('log_tutor').post(payload)
```